# How to use autodoc feature of sphinx in my README.rst?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a simple python library that provides a few api functions. Rather than publishing my docs to an external website, I'd rather just have my entire documentation (not long) in my README file.

Is it possible to use autodoc to document my api functions in my README file somehow to be displayed on github?

Comment: Is your README file `.md` (Markdown)? Usually output of Sphinx is in HTML, so what kind of format should your documentation output be generated to?

Comment: @bad_coder: in the title it says README.rst.

Comment: @mzjn I hadn't noticed the extension in the title, it doesn't say in the post's body.

Comment: GitHub can render ReST documents (example: https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/README.rst), but it will not process autodoc directives such as `automodule`.